# Multiple actions from multiple if / else if statements - R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm new to R and am experiencing a problem properly populating a column of data within a data frame.  I'm populating two columns (P_Score and P_Class) based on another column (P_Value) using a series of if / else if statements.

```
i<- 0
nr<- nrow(myData)
while(i<nr){
  i<-1+i
  if(toString(myData$P_Value[i])=="NA"){ myData$P_Score[i] <- myData$P_Value[i]
  } else if (as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))<5){
      myData$P_Score[i] <- 1; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Minimal Depression";
  } else if (as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))<10){
      myData$P_Score[i] <- 2; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Mild Depression";
  } else if (as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))<15){
      myData$P_Score[i] <- 3; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Moderate Depression";
  } else if (as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))<20){
      myData$P_Score[i] <- 4; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Moderate-Severe Depression";
  } else 
      myData$P_Score[i] <- 5; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Severe Depression";
}
```

However, this is not giving me my desired result, and instead I wind up with this:

```
P_Value  P_Score    P_Class
4        1          Severe Depression
25       5          Severe Depression
8        2          Severe Depression
13       3          Severe Depression
17       4          Severe Depression
1        1          Severe Depression
12       3          Severe Depression
```

So the P_Score is populating just fine, but the P_Class is always defaulting to "Severe Depression".   I must be having some issue executing multiple statements based off of 1 if condition, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have read elsewhere as long as you put semicolons after the statements both should work, but that's clearly not working.

I have also tried spacing out the commands like this:

```
} else if (as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))<5){
  myData$P_Score[i] <- 1
  myData$P_Class[i] <- "Minimal Depression"
```

But that does not seem to work either.  Please help!

Comment: First hint: using `for(i in 1:nr){`is more "natural" than `while(i<nr){  i<-1+i`.

Comment: Or instead of a loop use something like `grps <- cut(myData$P_Value, breaks=c(-Inf, 5, 10, 15, 20, Inf), labels=c("Min Dep", "Mild Dep", "Mod Dep", "Mod-Sev Dep", "Sev Dep"))`

Comment: The answer by @J_F is getting the point, since you have two statements after the else, you need to put them in a block.

Answer (score 5):

R has a function for this, there is no need for any loops. Please read `?cut`:

Set up example

```
myData
#   P_Value
# 1       4
# 2      25
# 3       8
# 4      13
# 5      17
# 6       1
# 7      12
# 8      NA

grps <- cut(myData$P_Value, 
          breaks=c(-Inf, 5, 10, 15, 20, Inf), 
          labels=c("Min Dep", "Mild Dep", "Mod Dep", "Mod-Sev Dep", "Sev Dep"))
```

With the groups created, we can make a Score and Class column from it

```
myData$P_Score <- as.numeric(grps)
myData$P_Class <- grps
myData
#   P_Value P_Score     P_Class
# 1       4       1     Min Dep
# 2      25       5     Sev Dep
# 3       8       2    Mild Dep
# 4      13       3     Mod Dep
# 5      17       4 Mod-Sev Dep
# 6       1       1     Min Dep
# 7      12       3     Mod Dep
# 8      NA      NA        <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
if (<condition>){
} else {
    if(<condition>){
    } else {
    }
}
```

Or:

```
ifelse(<condition>,
    ifelse(<condition>, <yes>, <no>)
)
```

So, in my opinion, you missed the `{}` after your `else` command.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your code is, that it always gives R the comand `myData$P_Class[i] <- "Severe Depression";`. As an example check out this code:

```
test <- 12
ret <- NA
if(test < 5){
  ret <- 1; print("Minimal");
}else if(test < 10){
  ret <- 2; print ("Mild");
}else if(test < 15){
  ret <- 3; print ("Moderate");
}else if(test < 20){
  ret <- 4; print ("Moderate-Severe");
}else ret<- 5;print("Severe Depression");
```

You should write instead for the last line `else{myData$P_Score[i] <- 5; myData$P_Class[i] <- "Severe Depression";}`. In doubt, always use more brackets than less. Here is my more reduced code (and I bet, it even gets smarter).

```
for(i in 1:nrow(myData)){
  tmp <- as.numeric(toString(myData$P_Value[i]))
  if(is.na(myData$P_Value[i])){
    myData$P_Score[i] <- myData$P_Value[i]
  } else if (tmp < 5){
    myData$P_Score[i] <- 1
    myData$P_Class[i] <- "Minimal Depression"
  } else if (tmp < 10){
    myData$P_Score[i] <- 2 
    myData$P_Class[i] <- "Mild Depression"
  } else if (tmp < 15){
    myData$P_Score[i] <- 3
    myData$P_Class[i] <- "Moderate Depression"
  } else if (tmp < 20){
    myData$P_Score[i] <- 4
    myData$P_Class[i] <- "Moderate-Severe Depression"
  } else{
    myData$P_Score[i] <- 5
  myData$P_Class[i] <- "Severe Depression"
  }
}
```